# No me cargan las imagenes al hacer npm build, subo la pagina al servidor y no andan, pero en local si

Tags: html, next.js

no me cargan las imagenes al subir el repositorio a internet
hice npm run build en next
puse la carpeta next dentro del servidor
y no me cargan las imagenes se ven asi =>

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes colocar mas información del código para observar como lo esta configurando

Comment: Si no aportas la parte de codigo que crees que te falla o algo no podremos ayudarte... por favor edita tu pregunta con el boton [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/550162/edit) y añade el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que al no estar la imagen en un servidor público esta no carge. Pero de todas formas se agradecería que subieras el código para ver si el fallo es otro. Un saludo.

Comment: Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges), podrás dejar comentarios para pedir aclaración al autor de la pregunta.